# Why the pop() or push() method of an array in the state of react can work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const { items } = this.state;
this.setState({ 
  items: this.state.items.slice(0, this.state.items.length - 1)
});
```

I know the code above can work well in react

However,

```
const { items } = this.state;
items.pop();
this.setState({ items });
```

I just don't know why this can still update the `dom` if there is a list rendered by the `this.state.items` (like `<div className="list">{this.state.items}</div>`).

I am confused that the `items.pop()` have changed the origin state, isn't the next state's items equal the origin state's items.Why this can still update the `dom` .

Comment: `.slice()` would also work, it has default parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are wondering why DOM changes if your mutation also applies the old state. You think "If I mutate the old one then both of the states points the same array's or object's reference". Yes, you are not creating a totally new array/object here but React [does not look for the references](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) I think.

React looks for many things but in your case, it looks for the DOM changes by diffing the elements, children of the array. Old DOM has one more element than the new DOM. Hence, it destroys the old one and mounts the new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just figure it out by myself, and you understand my right.

Comment: You are welcome :) In any case, it is better to select an answer to accept to close your question. You can provide an answer yourself how did you figure it out and explain how it works. Then, you can accept your answer if you don't want to accept other provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

The next state's items are not equal to the origin state's items because you are using an array mutable method (More info [MDN Mutable Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods)). This `pop` method modify the array directly, it does not generate a copy like others methods (`map, filter` no mutable methods).

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setState` will always rerender the component. It doesnt matter if the state actually changed. To change that behaviour, you have to implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: I know that `setState` would invoke the `render()` method, if `shouldComponentUpdate() `return true, I just don't know why the `dom` would change, since i think the origin state is equal to the next state. They both pop an element of the items list.

Comment: @lazysheep what? If render gets called the content changes?

Comment: I missed a point in my question, there is a list rendered by the items array.

Comment: @lazysheep why should that matter? the component does rerender, no matter what the children are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `React.Component` rather than `React.PureComponent`.

By default react will re-render on setState or if the parent re-renders even if the props or state didn't change. PureComponent however, does an equality check in `shouldComponentUpdate`, so that it won't re-render if all the props and state pass a strict equality check `===` (hence pure).

Answer (score 0):

Is your question why the second code block updates your component even though the component state is not changing? Both code blocks you posted cause your component to update because you are callingsetState() . If you take a look at the [documentation for setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) it says "**setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false**" . If you don't want your component to update then don't call setState().

Comment: I know that the `render` will be called, I just don't know why the `dom` will be updated, if there is a list rendered by `items`.Cause, I consider the both the previous items equals to the next items.They both pop an element of the items.